# executor.shutDownNow() does not stop inner methods from executing

Tags: java

I created a future task and submitted it to Executor. In the run() method i have created an object of placementPlanner.The method in this class calls other classes. However when i call executor.shutDownNow(), the inner methods invoked does not stops executing. How call i kill all the child threads and stop methods from being invoked. The code is below.

```
static List<Result> invokePlacementPlannerWithTimeout(int timeoutSecs,
        final String requestType, final RequestMap requestMap,
        final ReleaseMap releaseMap, final SysConfig systemConfig,
        final Request request, final SigmaBlade hostData,
        final ServiceLevelData serviceLevelData,
        final List<Service> serviceList, final String transactionID) throws IOException {

    /**
     * Object of ExecutorService interface used for timed execution of Placement
     * Planner.
     */
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    /**
     * Creating a final List of Result type.
     */
    final List<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();
    /**
     * set the executor thread working
     */
    Future<?> future = executor.submit(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                Result result = new Result();
                PlacementPlanner planner = new PlacementPlanner();

                result.setRequestMapACK(planner.getRequestResult(
                            requestMap, systemConfig, request, hostData,
                            serviceLevelData, transactionID,
                            configFileLocation));

                resultList.add(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in run method in invokePlacementPlannerWithTimeout method in Controller");
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    });

    try {
        /**
         * invoking the future task with specified timeout.
         */
        //  System.out.println(timeoutSecs);
        future.get(timeoutSecs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        /**
         * Shutting down the service after successful execution.
         */
        executor.shutdownNow();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /**
         * Shutting down the service if timeout is occured.
         */
        executor.shutdownNow();

        /**
         * Canceling the task for future use.
         */
        future.cancel(true);

        System.out.println("Timeout Occureed.");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM " + "QNSim.exe*");
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29)

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing
>   actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will
>   cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate

So, `shutdownNow()` doesn't guarantee that task terminates immediately.

Comment: (What you should do is make your threads properly interruptible.  [This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) is probably the best source on how to properly handle interruptions.

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** need to stop that thread, you may consider using the deprecated `Thread.stop()` as that't the only effective way to do this. But only after carefully reading the `@deprecated` section of the javadoc.

(I expect lots of downvotes for this answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `future.cancel()` if you want to cancel the task which will interruptrunning task if `mayInterruptIfRunning` value is true. 
`shutdownNow` will eventually try to cancel threads with  `Thread.interrupt()` which I guess you don't want to do.

Another way is check [Thread.isInterrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) status in your run method if it true just break then your code will break when you call `shutdownNow` or `cancel`